# Delete child collection without using include in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to delete a child collection without loading the entities in EF

```
public Class Student : Entity 
{ 
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    Public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public Class Course : Entity 
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set }
}

public class UpdateCourseInput 
{
    public Long CourseId { get; set }
    public List<Long> RemovedStudents { get; set; }
}
```

**What doesn't work**

If I want to delete student course without using `.Include`, I get an error that `childCollection` is null

```
void async Task UpdateCourse(UpdateCourseInput input) 
{
     var course = _CourseRepository.GetAll()
                                   .Where(c => c.id--input.CourseId )
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

     foreach (var id in input.RemovedStudents)
     {
         // loading student without hitting database 
         var student = _StudentRepository.Load(id)
         course.Students.Remove(student)
     }
}
```

**What works**

This has performance drawback when child collection is big, the model is simplified model, but in real case the collection include byte arrays and etc..

```
void async Task UpdateCourse(UpdateCourseInput input)
{
     var course = _CourseRepository.GetAll()
                                   .Where(c => c.id--input.CourseId )
                                   .Include(c => c.Students)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

     foreach (var id in input.RemovedStudents)
     {
          // loading student without hitting database 
          var student = _StudentRepository.Load(id)
          course.Students.Remove(student)
     }
}
```

How can I delete a child collection without using `.Include`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do lazy loading by adding "virtual"

```
public Class Student : Entity 
{ 
   public string Firstname { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public Class Course : Entity 
{
   public String Title { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set }
}
```

Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual. Without virtual, lazy loading will not be supported, and you get null on collection properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

> DbContext has methods called Entry and Entry, these methods
>   get a DbEntityEntry for the given entity and provide access to the
>   information about the entity and return a DbEntityEntry object able to
>   perform the action on the entity. Now we can perform the delete
>   operation on the context by just changing the entity state to
>   EntityState.Deleted

```
using (Entities Context = new Entities())   
{   
    DepartmentMaster deptDelete = new DepartmentMaster { DepartmentId = 6 };   
    Context.Entry(deptDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;   
    Context.SaveChanges();   
}
```

or

```
var employer = new Employ { Id = 1 };

//Attach the entity to context
ctx.Employ.Attach(employer);

//Remove
ctx.Employ.Remove(employer);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```